# How can I show a bootstrap modal in dart?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dart, angular-dart

I need to avoid using the data-toggle attribute to open the use component. Instead of it I use ng-click="ctrl.openModal".
How can I use the modal to show / hide with Dart? I want to know how to use it like in javascript but in dart.
EDIT: I don't want to use any other third party plugins or functionalities like bootjack, etc...

What i need is to do like in bootstrap documentation:

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

SOLVED: I used dart:js to do it in this way.

first:

```dart
// imports dart library
import 'dart:js' as js;
```

then:

```dart
 js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['#myModal'])
        .callMethod('modal', [new js.JsObject.jsify({'show': 'true'})]);
```

Addition:
if you want to close the modal the boostrap documentation says:

```dart
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

To do this in DART, we do:

```dart
//this closes the modal window
js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['#myModal'])
    .callMethod('modal', ['hide']);
```

Comment: Are you using Angular UI Bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ )?

Comment: JS Angular-UI can't be used in Dart but you could use the Dart port http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular_ui. How would you do it in JavaScipt? If you are using vanilla Bootstrap with ShadowDOM, Bootstrap components might not work.

Comment: When you found a solution to your question you can just answer your question by adding an answer. Adding the answer inside question is not  a good option. It might be though that your reputation doesn't allow you to answer your own question yet. For me it's not obvious anymore what the initial question was.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use Bootjack? It provides a very nice API for exactly the things you want to do.

Comment: I don't use bootjack due to, project configuration. we don't want to add a new library just to use one of the utilities.